# Entity Framework: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 in a Azure API web application in a VS2015 solution. I have a table EmailAddresses in an Azure SQL database. The primary key of the table consists of two columns, a PersonID and an EmailAddressID column. The last column is an identity column so the value should be generated by the database.
I generated the EF model from the database and didn't do any manual modifications to the generated model. When I try to insert a new email address record to the database, EF trows the exception 'Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'EmailAddress' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.'. When I check the generated SQL statement, the column EmailAddressID is included in the insert statement. The parameter for the PersonID is set to the right value, but the value for the EmailAddressID is 0. EmailAddressID shouldn't be even included in the SQL statement since this would be an identity generated value. How do I fix this in my model?

Comment: Probably including the identity column in a composite PK (which btw makes no any sense) confuses EF code and it takes wrong decision.

Comment: It sounds like you want the EmailAddressID as the PK, with maybe another (unique) index on PersonId + EMailAddressID

Comment: I changed the PK to only include the EmailAddressID. After that, I regenerated the EF model from the database, but the behaviour is still the same. I checked the model and the EmailAddressID is the only property that has set EntityKey to true.